# Python: max(a list of numbers as characters) gives right and wrong answer

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, max

So here's the exact scenario- consider the list:

`x=['4', '5', '29', '54', '4', '0', '-214', '542', '-64', '1', '-3', '6', '-6']` 
now `max(x)` should give ***'542'*** instead it gives **'6'**, but if you take out **'6'** it does give **'542'** as max. `min(x)` on the other hand correctly gives **'-214'** as the answer.

if you convert **x** into a list of numbers then obviously `max(x)` gives the correct output **542**. This is an unreliable behavior at least from what I know about Python and I would like to explore if I am missing something here on how `max()` function works that could explain this behavior.

Comment: you are considering string not int.

Comment: Consider thumbing through a dictionary. You'd expect it to be in alphabetical order. And for instance, "alpha" would be before "alphabetical". That's what's happening here. Lexographically, something starting with "5" is smaller than "6" for the same reason "B" words follow "A" words in the dictionary. Its reliable... although mixing multinational symbols with unicode can be perplexing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I was writing this question and trying to understand this behavior with `max()` function, I tried `x.sort()` and it gave out the answer. So let me paste the sorted list:

**['-214', '-3', '-6', '-64', '0', '1', '29', '4', '4', '5', '54', '542', '6']**

So basically these are strings and initial character of the string decides its value as string. Meaning, `5kaify` will come first than `6kaify` .

For more clarity, if I add bunch of alphabets into this list as below:

`x=['4', '5', '29', '54', '4', '0',`**`'d'`**`, '-214', '542', '-64', '1',`**`'a'`**`, '-3',`**`'c'`**`, '6', '-6']`

`max(x)` will give **`'d'`** as the answer as alphabetically it would come later than all the strings in the list, hence **`max()`** checks for alphabetical order as the value for list of strings/characters and not its integral/numeric value. Hope this was helpful.

Comment: Good answer but could use a bit of rewording. Its not that the initial character decides its value, they are all considered in turn.

Answer (score 1):

You are taking string not int. While taking string: they are sorted alphabetically.

**`x.sort()`:**

```
['-214', '-3', '-6', '-64', '0', '1', '29', '4', '4', '5', '54', '542', '6']
```

You need to use map to convert them into int.

```
max(map(int,x))

# 542
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach,

```
>>> x=['4', '5', '29', '54', '4', '0', '-214', '542', '-64', '1', '-3', '6', '-6']
>>> 
>>> max(x, key=lambda x : int(x))
'542'
>>> min(x, key=lambda x : int(x))
'-214'
```

Answer (score 0):

So essentially max and min when using a string will use alphabetically highest character. Think of the array

['all','b','c','d']

max will list d as the answer as when sorting alphabetically we first rely on the initial character and only with duplicates do we check the next character.

So when we try to sort numbers as a string it will use the same logic. Therefore 6 will be higher than 562 since 6 > 5.

Alphabetically the order is symbols < numbers (in order 0-9) < characters (in order a-z)

I hope that answers your question.